# Lounge access for work and sleep in Dubai T3 before connecting to T2?

Tags: transit, dubai, emirates, lounges, flydubai

Has anyone arrived at T3 in Dubai and used the business class lounge there before connecting via T2? I have a 12 hour layover due to a flight change and need both sleep and work space, is this available?

Note: I am a skywards gold member